'dot' added to PATH, but graphviz still can't execute it
I'm having issues getting python graphviz to find 'dot' in the PATH environment variable. This seems to be a well-documented problem, but I still can't seem to get past it.
I have added graphviz to the PATH and restarted my IDE and computer afterwards. I can verify that I did this right because I can call 'dot' from the command line. However, graphviz still cannot find 'dot' for some reason. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled graphviz which didn't work. I am using version 0.20.1.
Any ideas as to what is going wrong? Any help is much appreciated.
Here is an example code and full stack trace of the error:
import graphviz
g = graphviz.Digraph('G', filename='hello.gv')
g.edge('Hello', 'World')
g.view()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\.python_env\library\site-packages\graphviz\backend\execute.py", line 81, in run_check
    proc = subprocess.run(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ graphviz_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    g.view()
  File "C:\Users\.python_env\library\site-packages\graphviz\_tools.py", line 171, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\.python_env\library\site-packages\graphviz\rendering.py", line 186, in view
    cleanup=cleanup, quiet=quiet, quiet_view=quiet_view)
  File "C:\Users\.python_env\library\site-packages\graphviz\_tools.py", line 171, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\.python_env\library\site-packages\graphviz\rendering.py", line 122, in render
    rendered = self._render(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\.python_env\library\site-packages\graphviz\_tools.py", line 171, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\.python_env\library\site-packages\graphviz\backend\rendering.py", line 327, in render
    capture_output=True)
  File "C:\Users\.python_env\library\site-packages\graphviz\backend\execute.py", line 84, in run_check
    raise ExecutableNotFound(cmd) from e
graphviz.backend.execute.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute 'dot', make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH


Is your Python code using graphviz started from this same command line where you tested that dot can be found, or is it started a different way (f/e, from an IDE or GUI)? You haven't told us which OS you're running, but if you're on something UNIXy, adjusting the PATH used on shell startup doesn't necessarily change the PATH used for things that aren't started from a shell.

A good place to start is to, in the same Python interpreter having the problem, import os and print(os.environ['PATH']), then compare that output to the value you expect.

Assuming that shows a different PATH than the one your command-line terminal sessions have, which specific IDE are you using? Some of them let you set up a PATH in the "Run Configuration" (or similar) settings.

(There are other possible issues as well -- one common problem we see is folks installing their IDE with Snap or another package manager that sets up a sandbox that deliberately stops programs from accessing software other than declared dependencies, f/e; one can get a similar effect from a devcontainer created by VS Code; but all of this would require a lot more details to investigate, and could also be ruled out if you tried running your program direct from the terminal without an IDE at all)

I'm using windows 10 and working in a jupyter notebook from VSCode, neither of which is the issue. when I run my the code from a .py file instead of .ipynb, in pycharm or the command prompt instead of VSCode, it get the same error. when I print os.environ['PATH'], I see the path to graphviz.

First: Does import shutil; print(shutil.which('dot'))  find the executable? If it doesn't, does shutil.which('dot.exe') do better? Second: Please [edit] the question to show the full/complete stack trace, so we can see exactly which line within the graphviz library threw the error. (I could believe if the library wasn't tested on Windows -- that's not the ecosystem graphviz comes from, which is why I'm wondering about 'dot' vs 'dot.exe' -- but we'll be better placed to diagnose once we've seen the full error).

Edited the post with the full stack trace. Interestingly, shutil.which('dot') works but shutil.which('dot.exe') does not. That might be the problem here.

Hmm. Did you maybe install graphviz via conda? IIUC, it creates a .bat wrapper rather than putting the .exe location directly in the PATH; if that's the problem here, then https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/issues/65 is relevant.

No, I installed with pip

Um. I wasn't asking how you installed the Python module, but the executable package. pip doesn't install OS-native executables (whereas conda sometimes does).

I don't use conda and I've never explicitly installed any executable. All I did was pip install graphviz. I assumed that the python module would automatically build and manage any executable that it would need. But you're right -- it looks like pip didn't install any executable because I cant seem to find any .exe files anywhere. What was I supposed to do differently?

You were supposed to download and install graphviz (the portable non-Python-specific package) from https://graphviz.org/

(since you didn't ever install graphviz, I'm curious what exactly you added to your PATH)

I added the directory to the python site package haha. Theres a file called dot.py in the python package and it was picking that up. thank you for your help.

Here is where the "real" Graphviz system lives: https://graphviz.org/download/

So the real graphviz executable is a separate thing, and the python package is just used call it from within a python script?

That's right -- the Python package is just a wrapper.

ah that makes sense! Thank you
